# postgresql change index order

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I created an index as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name_desc_idx
          ON table_name
       USING btree (updated_at ASC)
```

now: ASC was an error, I need to change it to DESC. I'm trying several things with ALTER INDEX however nothing seems to work and I'm afraid the only thing to do is to remove the index and recreate it. Is there a way to edit the index ordering?

Comment: Why don't you want to delete and create ?

Comment: Why do you think a descending order is better? You just have a single column in your index.

Comment: If there were a way, it would still need locks...

Comment: @FrankHeikens it's because the DELETE operation is like 'WHERE updated_at < NOW() - INTERVAL' so ordering from the most recent sound better (but does it make sense technically?)

Comment: @FrankHeikens the DELETE right now is very slow, this is an attempt to improve perfomance, does it make sense? (sorry for the double reply, I wanted to add this info)

Comment: @JoulinRouge: Without a query plan (explain(analyse, verbose, buffers)  ... ) how can you know that this is/was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm afraid the only thing to do is to remove the index

Don't be afraid, You can do it without any downtime :

- first create your new index in the good order, but with [`CONCURRENTLY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) to avoid any lock,
- then, drop the old index.

No lock, and no query without index, with the only downside of having a 2n index size while you do the change.